# Leda 6.3 Free edition on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, leda

I am new to LEDA 6.3 and I would like to use it on ubuntu.
I downloaded the FREE EDITION of LEDA but cannot set the paths as specified by the instructions.

Do I have to set the path in the free edition?
Any installation help is really appreciated.

How to run and compile my LEDA project?

Answer (score 0):

1. LEDA 6.3, Free Edition include: libleda.so, libleda.a, header files
2. Extract:

   ```
   gunzip your_donwload_file.tar.gz
   tar xvf your_download_file.tar
   ```
3. HelloWorld Makefile

   ```
   CXXFLAGS = -DLEDA_MULTI_THREAD

   LEDAROOT = path_to_your_leda_folder
   OBJS = HelloWorld.o

   LIBS = -Wl,-rpath=$(LEDAROOT) -L$(LEDAROOT) -lleda -lX11 -lm
   INCLUDE = -I$(LEDAROOT)/incl
   CXXFLAGS += $(INCLUDE)

   TARGET = HelloWorld

   $(TARGET): $(OBJS)
       $(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

   all: $(TARGET)

   clean:
       rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
   ```